# table naming and organizing of tables in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, naming-conventions

I'm trying to organize my PosgtresSql tables according to the application components they correspond to. For example, tables related to 'story' such as 'story_contents', 'story_comments', 'story_layout': would it best to keep a simple '*' naming convention as presented? Would there be any drawback to using a '.' instead of '*'? ... or is there a best practice that I'm completely overlooking?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:**

Sure, if you place the entire database/table/column name reference in quotes

**Long answer:**

In Postgres, and most other databases, the dot is used to separate database name from table name, and table name from column name.  For example, if you had a database called `MyDB`, with a table called `MyTable` and column in that table `MyCol`, then you could write the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT MyDB.MyTable.MyCol
FROM MyDB.MyTable
```

*However*, if your database, table, and/or column names themselves had dots in them, then doing a `SELECT` might not work.  In this case, I believe you can escape the fully qualified name (or portion) with quotes.  So, if you had a column called `MyCol.Col1`, you could do the following:

```
SELECT "MyDB.MyTable.MyCol.Col1"
FROM MyDB.MyTable
```

The comment by @vector seems to be pointing in the right direction (no pun intended), and you should lean towards using underscores or some other character to separate out your schema names, rather than using a dot.

Comment: Indeed, the '.' would just cause more trouble that it's worth.